# Using submit button to send insted of Enter key

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of code

```
// watch textarea for release of key press
        $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                var text = $(this).val();
                var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
                var length = text.length;
                // send 
                if (length <= maxLength + 1) {
                    chat.send(text, name);
                    $(this).val("");
                } else {
                    $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
                }
            }
        });
```

What it does it that it sends a message typed in a textarea to a certain email address once someone hits the enter button. How can i change this to use a submit button as in the code below?

```
< div id="page-wrap">
        < form id="send-message-area">
            < p>Your message: </p>
            < textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' placeholder ="Send Your Message">  < /textarea>
    < input type="submit">
        < /form>

    < /div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#send-message-area").on("submit", function (e) {
var text = $("#sendie").val();
var maxLength = $("#sendie").attr("maxlength");
var length = text.length;
// send 
if (length <= maxLength + 1) {
        chat.send(text, name);
    alert(text);
        $("#sendie").val("");
} else {
        $("#sendie").val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

check sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXKfY/)

Answer (score 2):

So attach the code to the submission of the form

```
$("#send-message-area").on("submit", function (e) {
    var elem = $("#sendie");
    var text = elem.val();
    var maxLength = parseInt(elem.attr("maxlength"),10);
    var length = text.length;
    // send 
    if (length <= maxLength + 1) {
            chat.send(text, name);
            elem.val("");
    } else {
            elem.val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```